# How to log exception stack trace in Json object with out breaking with log4j2

Tags: java, json, log4j2, splunk

**Environment**

I have implemented `log4j` in my application successfully. I have used following pattern loayout:

```
{"a":"%X{Id}","b":"%d","message":"%m","priority":"%p","Exception":"%ex"}
```

It is logging as json format with my custom attributes.

But while logging exception with %ex it is printing whole trace, i want it but it is breaking json format.

**Question**

So can you please suggest me to put whole stack trace in json without breaking.

Comment: Do you use the [JSON Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) of Log4j2?

Comment: Why don't you raise this on the Log4j 2 issue tracker? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Answer (score 2):

In the log4j `Patternlayout` configuration you could use `%enc{%ex}{CRLF}` which is replacing `\n` and `\r` with respectively `\\n` and `\\r`.

Applied to you sample:

```
{"a":"%X{Id}","b":"%d","message":"%m","priority":"%p","Exception":"%enc{%ex}{CRLF}"}
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Answer (score 0):

StrackTrace contains new line chars.. which is probably breaking the JSON...why don't you use getMessage() instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply. but i am using log4j's  pattern layout attributes(default). %ex to log whole exception(to identify everything where it happened ) so please let me know if u know any thing to remove new line chars.

Comment: Did you get the answer? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JSON library for this like so:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

object.put("ID", idVariable);
object.put("Exception", exceptionVariable);
object.put("Priority", priorityVariable);

object.toString();
```

or use :

object.toString(2);

for indentation (pretty print)

You can then use the object to pass it to a method for the Log4j logger

library for JSON found here [JSON Library](http://www.json.org/java/)

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply. but i am using log4j's  pattern layout attributes(default). %ex to log exception so i need any pre defined attributs to remove new line chars.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using JSON encoding format `%enc{%ex}{JSON}`, replacing `%ex`.

Your pattern layout will look like this:

```
{"a":"%X{Id}","b":"%d","message":"%m","priority":"%p","Exception":"%enc{%ex}{JSON}"}
```

source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout